# How can I prevent Prettier from breaking a single line into multiple lines when closing tags in my code?

Tags: javascript, html, prettier, prettier-vscode

I want to keep my code like this:

```
    <div>
      <form action="">
        <button type="button" onClick={() => setsearchStr('Random')}>Text</button>
      </form>
    </div>
```

But prettier changes it to:

```
    <div>
      <form action="">
        <button type="button" onClick={() => setsearchStr('Random')}>
          Text
        </button>
      </form>
    </div>
```

How can i achieve this?

Thanks

I already have this config:

```
{
  "trailingComma": "es5",
  "tabWidth": 2,
  "semi": true,
  "singleQuote": true,
  "arrowParens": "avoid",
  "printWidth": 130,
  "bracketSameLine": true
}
```

Comment: see [HTML whitespace sensitivity](https://prettier.io/docs/en/options.html#html-whitespace-sensitivity) or increase your `printWidth`

Answer (score 0):

Hi you can achieve this by adding :

```
    "singleAttributePerLine": false,
```

to your prettier config.

Hope it works for you !

[Single Attribute per Line](https://prettier.io/docs/en/options.html#single-attribute-per-line)